# „Gehören“ als Ersatz für „gebühren”

Tags: word-usage, usage, dialect, colloquial

In [einem Eintrag](https://contribute.dict.cc/?action=show-history&id=752538) im Online-Wörterbuch [dict.cc](https://dict.cc) steht Folgendes, welches mich ziemlich überraschte:

> sb. is entitled to sth. [desirable] — jdm. gehört etw. [gebührt] [ [österr.] [südd.] [schweiz.]

Stimmt das so, wie geschrieben? Ich kenne den Einsatz von „gehören“ im Sinne von „verdienen“ oder „sollen“: *Sie gehört besser bezahlt*, *Der Junge gehört bestraft* usw., und glaubte bisher, das wäre etwas aus dem südlichen deutschsprachigen Raum.

Ist aber „gehören“ als Synonym von „gebühren“ wirklich etwas Südliches? Suche entweder mit Quellen belegten Antworten oder Norddeutsche, die das aus reinem Sprachgefühl beantworten können.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laut [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geh%C3%B6ren#d-1-3-2) sei dieser Gebrauch von **gehören** im Sinne von **gebühren** auch außerhalb Süddeutschlands und Österreichs üblich, wenn auch *umgangssprachlich*. Diese Information fehlt dem Eintrag bei dict.cc, was nicht verwunderlich ist, weil dort jeder Eintragungen vornehmen kann.

Wenn ich (in *Nordostdeutschland* aufgewachsen) mir die im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geh%C3%B6ren#d-1-3-2) aufgeführten Beispiele anschaue, klingen sie auch nicht sonderlich ungewöhnlich:

> **3.**
>
> …
>
> *süddeutsch, österreichisch, umgangssprachlich*   jmdm. gebührt etw.
>
> <sub>BEISPIELE:</sub>
>
>   dem **gehört** ein Denkzettel
>
>   dem **gehört** alles weggenommen *(= dem sollte man alles wegnehmen)* <sub>[BAIERL, *Flinz*, 8]</sub>
>
>   die Gedärme **gehören** euch herausgerissen <sub>[BRECHT, *Trommeln*, III]</sub>

Lediglich das erste Beispiel sticht für mich als Ellipse etwas hervor (ich würde hinter *Denkzettel* ein *verpasst* hinzufügen).

Comment: bei den anderen Beispielen folgt immer ein Verb, klingt ein bisschen wie "vergessen" beim Eintrag-verfassen. Ich würde auch ein *verpasst* anfügen.

Comment: Was ich auch mit dieser guten Antwort noch nicht ganz zusammenbringe, ist, ob dieser Gebrauch von "gehören" als  Übersetzung von "sb. is entitled to sth." in Frage kommt. Als Übersetzung von "sb deserves sth" kann ich mir das gut vorstellen, aber "entitled"? Dazu fällt mir kein Beispiel ein -- euch?

Comment: @HalvarF Dein Kommentar macht mir klar, dass ich das gar nicht mal in Frage gestellt habe. Ich habe schlichtweg angenommen, dass der o.g. Gebrauch gemeint wurde. „Entitled“ erscheint meistens in Verbindung mit Positivem, wohingegen fast jedes Beispiel eher negativ wirkt. Deshalb die erneute und leicht verfeinerte Frage: Wird das im Süden wirklich so benutzt?

Comment: @NumerisaysReinstateMonica, ob die englische Übersetzung tatsächlich *entitled* ist, spielt doch überhaupt keine Rolle, zumal beim *German StackExchange*. Die Antwort (dass es *umgangsprachlich* überall, also sowohl im Süden als auch im Norden vorkommt) ändert sich ja nicht dadurch, wie man es im Englischen sagt.

Comment: Naja, die Frage war ja erstmal, ob "gehören" als Übersetzung von "be entitled to" richtig ist. "To be entitled" heißt m.E. eher "berechtigt sein" als "verdienen", "gebühren", "gehören" oder? D.h. diese Frage müsste man letztlich trotzdem mit Nein beantworten?

Comment: @HalvarF Ja, du hast mehr oder weniger Recht. Denn meine ursprüngliche Frage entstand aus der Überraschung, dass diese mir bekannte, umgangssprachliche Formulierung im Norden fehlt. Da irrte ich mich, indem ich annahm, dass mit „entitled/gebührt“ die Phrase „ihm gehört gelobt/belohnt/ein Denkzettel verpasst“ gemeint wurde. Also meine eigentlich Frage basierte sich auf ein Missverständnis. Die Antwort ist lediglich, dass „gehört“ überall so benutzt wird und dass jener Gebrauch der Bedeutung „entitled/gebührt“ nicht entspricht, oder?

Answer (score 3):

Ich weiß nicht, ob das Muster

> Etwas gehört getan
> <sup>gleichbedeutend: *Etwas sollte getan werden*</sup>

und seine um ein Dativobjekt erweiterte Variante

> Jemandem gehört etwas (an)getan
> <sup>gleichbedeutend: *Jemandem sollte etwas (an)getan werden* (um ihn zu bestrafen)</sup>

nur im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums gängig ist, oder ob man es überall verwendet. In Österreich, wo ich lebe, gehören jedenfalls beide Varianten zur Alltagssprache, und Ö1, der Kultur-Radiosender des ORF verwendet seit vielen Jahren sogar einen Werbeslogan der nach diesem Muster gestrickt ist:

> Ö1 gehört gehört
> <sup>bedeutet: *Ö1 sollte gehört werden*</sup>

Meinen Recherchen zufolge verwendet auch der deutschländische Radiosender SWR1 den gleichen Slogan oder hat ihn früher mal verwendet. Aber auch dieser Sender ist nicht gerade in Norddeutschland daheim.

Im Alltag hört man oft Sätze wie diese, die diesem Muster entsprechen:

> Die Butter gehört aufgebraucht bevor sie ranzig wird.
> Der Rasenmäher gehört schon dringend repariert.
> Dein Zimmer gehört aufgeräumt.

Wenn man dieses Muster um einen Dativus incommodi (Dativ des Leidtragenden bzw. Benachteiligten) erweitert, dann entsteht ein Gefüge, durch das ausgedrückt wird, dass eine Handlung ausgeführt werden soll, um jemandem einen Schaden zuzufügen, meist um ihn damit zu bestrafen:

> Dem Georg gehört eine Ohrfeige verpasst.
> <sup>*Jemand sollte dem Georg mal eine Ohrfeige verpassen.*</sup>
> Dem kriminellen Bankdirektor gehört sämtliches Geld weggenommen.
> <sup>*Jemand sollte dem kriminellen Bankdirektor sämtliches Geld wegnehmen.*</sup>
> Den Politikern gehört endlich mal ein Denkzettel verpasst.
> <sup>*Jemand sollte den Politikern endlich mal einen Denkzettel verpassen.*</sup>

Nicht zufällig ist in zwei der drei Beispiel die Rede davon jemandem etwas zu "verpassen". Weil die Fügung

> Jemandem gehört etwas verpasst

so häufig ist, wird dabei manchmal das Wort *verpasst* weggelassen, und die so entstandene Ellipse hat dann dieses Muster:

> Jemandem gehört etwas

Beispiele:

> Dem Georg gehört eine Ohrfeige.
> Den Politikern gehört endlich mal ein Denkzettel.

Diese Form des "gehören" hat aber nichts mit einer Besitzzuschreibung zu tun (*»Georg gehört das rote Auto«*), was man am letzten Beispiel auch durch den Zusatz *»endlich mal«* erkennt, der bei einer Besitzangabe nur wenig Sinn ergeben würde.

Comment: Danke sehr. Meine eigentliche Frage bleibt aber leider unbeantwortet. Gibt es einen überzeugenden Grund, warum das mit [österr.] [südd.] [schweiz.] versehen wurde?

Comment: @NumerisaysReinstateMonica: Da ich seit meiner Geburt im Osten Österreichs lebe (ca. 30 Jahre Graz, 20 Jahre Wien, 5 Jahre St. Pölten), kann ich zur Verbreitung nur beisteuern, dass es dort wo ich lebe zur alltäglichen Sprache gehört. Über den Status jenseits des Weißwurstäquators müssten sich ein paar Nordlichter zu Wort melden. (Nur zur Sicherheit: Den Begriff "Nordlicht" meine ich durchaus freundlich und nett.)